# No connection with new Ethernet wiring when plugging in an Nvidia shield

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I ran my own ethernet cable yesterday to my living room, with the sole purpose being it would connect straight to my Nvidia shield. I ran line last night, no problems.

This morning, no problems.

Later in the day, I plugged new ethernet cable into my Nvidia shield, and thats where the problem occurred. Shield said signal strenghth was excellent, however nothing would load.

My 2 guests lost the Wi-Fi on their phones, my computer, which is connected to an entirely different ethernet cable on the second floor would not work, and my cordless phone which is also upstairs, would not work. I unplug from shield, everything works.

I originally ran a new ethernet cable into my living room from the outlet box outside my home. I ran my new cable from outlet box straight into my Nvidia shield, without using a router. When I was adding my new cable, I undid the first set of the wires that the phone company ran, and added my ethernet cable along with the original wires I undid.

At that point, my computer (Which was running off existing ethernet cable, on out of my modem) worked, along with my landline. When I plug the new cable I added into the shield, my phone cuts out, there is no Wi-Fi, and the shield won't load. I ran line last night, and there were no problems. This morning, again, no problems.

Later in the day, I plugged new ethernet cable into my Nvidia shield, and thats where the problem occurred. Shield said signal strenghth was excellent to my shield, however nothing would load. My 2 guests lost the Wi-Fi on their phones, my computer, which is connected to an entirely different ethernet cable on the second floor would not work, and my cordless phone which is also upstairs, would not work. I unplugged it from shield, and everything worked again.

The only thing I can think of is when I incorporated the wires in the box outside, I "twisted" the small wires inside the cat5 to the existing wires that were run months ago.

Comment: It is not clear the reason you reference the fact the signal strength is strong if you connected the device directly to an ethernet connection.  Signal strength is almost uniformly used to indicated you are connected wirelessly.

Comment: I threw that in because I ran the ethernet directly to the nvidia shield. I did not use modem.When I went into settings on the shield, it showed the connection was excellent. I don't know if this clarifies what you asked.

Comment: I think we don't have quite enough information.  Until you provide the right details, it may be hard for some of our experts to know just which details we still need.  Maybe what is plugged in on the other side of the Ethernet port. I'm suspecting "Rogue DHCP" (which, despite the name, doesn't necessarily imply malware). Knowing the IP addresses when things work, and when they don't, maybe very helpful. Yes, I know this request for information may take a bit of time to fulfill, and maybe I'm wrong and someone can spot the problem. But I also might be right, in which case we may need this info.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I did not use modem."  I'm assuming you plugged one end into your router, though?  Also, how long is the cable?

Comment: I originally ran a new ethernet cable into my living room from the outlet box outside my home. I ran my new cable from outlet box straight into my Shield, without using a router. When I was adding my new cable, I undid the first set of the wires that the phone company ran, and added my ethernet cable along with the original wires I undid.At that point, my computer (Which was running off existing ethernet cable, on out of my modem) worked, along with my landline. When I plug the new cable I added into the Shield, my phone cuts out,there is no wifi, and the shield won't load. Is this any better?

Comment: You have provided some additional information, but your question is currently formatted as a single paragraph, which makes it incredibly difficult to read.

Comment: @Ramhound For some odd reason the original poster rolled back my edit that made it actually readable. To the original poster: **When a question is readable you get a better chance to get help.**

Comment: I tried editing it to break it up. The box with my question inside it can be edited, which I did, but it keeps showing up in the form you see. This is my first time on this site, so please forgive me.

Comment: What happens if you connect a laptop to said cable?  Can it lease an IP address?  Did you buy the cable premade?  Did you crimp the ends on yourself and maybe mix up some of the wires?

Comment: I don't own a laptop.I bought the cable pre made. I just cut one end off, seperated the wires, and connected the to the posts. It was color coded, so no mixup there.

Comment: @JakeGould - It was not intentional.  They added information and failed to see the notification the question was edited.

Comment: @Ramhound fair enough. I believe I have edited it again to be formatted and also add the new information.

Comment: If the Shield is disconnected from the network.  Do other devices work after an appropriate reboot of all networking equipment?

Comment: If shield is disconnect, everything works without a reboot. When my shield is plugged in downstairs, my router, which is on seperate line, doesn't connect.Same with my cordless phone.

Comment: What do you mean your cordless phones?  Your cordless phones are wireless, and are not even traditionally connected to a network, why isn't the fact if the Shield is disconnected everything works included in your question body?  The more information you provide indicates the wire you have run is the source of the problem or you have a DHCP configuration conflict.

Comment: What do I mean by "Cordless Phone"? I mean my cordless phone doesn't work when my new ethernet cable is plugged in to my Shield. I wanted to stress the fact that I didn't mean a CELL PHONE.